# Does ext4 have any issues when I have curly braces in folder names?

Tags: filesystems, filenames, ext4

I decided to rip some of my Audio CDs to FLAC and although I try to avoid special characters in the name of the folders I named some of my folders with curly braces:

```
1973 - Aerosmith {1993 Remaster}
```

I do not use the terminal for accessing these folders or the files inside them. I tend to use curly braces for something that's not part of the album title. The reason I don't use `()` or `[]` is because there are releases with parentheses and brackets in the album title so I needed something more unique. The `{}` seems to be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The ext4 filesystem should have no problem with any ASCII character in a file name or other path
element (folder, directory) except for / and \0 (the null byte).  If an album has a / in the title, you may have to handle that specially.

On the other hand, many shells (and thus shell scripts) may need special characters to be single ‘quoted’ or \backslash escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. If you were to access the files via `bash` you would have to quote them with `\`. Unix/Linux filename standards allow any character in filenames, except `NUL (0x00)` and slash "`/`".